# Computing the SHA256 hash of a FileResponse objects content

Tags: python, django, hash, byte, sha256

I have a file for which I have computed its SHA256Sum and have verified it is correct.

```
hash1 = computeSHA256(filepath)
```

I need to compute the hash again, but this time using the values inside `response.streaming_content` where response is a Django FileResponse object, which I have done as follows:

```
response = FileResponse(request, open(filepath, 'rb'), content_type='application/json')
content = b''.join(response.streaming_content)
h = hashlib.sha256()
h.update(str(content).encode('utf-8'))
hash2 = h.hexdigest()
```

This issue here is that `hash1 != hash2`. For example:

```
hash1 = 7836496a8e17dac5aad5dea15409b06558d0feaf6c39198eae620afebb1fa097
hash2 = 70a3e07b20e722652740e93702b70322d042b9710b3087228e70551ad8301086
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong to cause the two hash values to not be equal?

Note: the file is a Google Protobuf (.pbf) file, so is binary.

Comment: first I would check if both files have the same content - ie. using programs like `diff` or `meld`. Maybe they are different - event one space or new-line can change hash.